# Почему Safari не работает с flexbox?

Tags: html, css

С помощью флекс бокс перемещаю блоки.

```
.inter_par .inter_row {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-box;
    flex-direction: column;

}
.inter_row .fl.real {
    order: 2;
}
.inter_row .fr {
    order: 1;
}
```

Везде работает но только не в Сафари. Подскажите пожалуйста, как быть?

Comment: а сафари 6 или выше ? если да то сафари поддерживает это свойство с префикстом -webkit- но если это сафари мобил то опять же с -webkit- но и версия сафари должна быть 7+ , https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/flex

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Comment: Elena Semenchenko - вроде с github получается , https://geyanpeaple.github.io/ , https://geyanpeaple.github.io/flex/ так и должно быть что бы нельзя было не под директорию создать а директорию ?